# data center in poland

Tags: hosting, datacenter

Could you recommend some datacenter in Europe/Poland ??? Tier-3 or Tier-2.

Answer (score 2):

lets check Telehouse.Poland http://en.telehouse.pl/

```
* Over 3,700 sq m (aprox. 40,000 sq feet) of technical space  — one of the largest DCs in Poland
* Guaranteed 9 MW power supply
* Capable of ceiling loads exceeding 1 ton per sq m (max. 1,500 kg per sq m, max. rack weight: 2,500 kg)
* More than 200 carriers in Telco.Ring
* Meets Tier III DataCenter requirements
* Located in Warsaw's business center (approx. 2.5 km from the airport)
* Completion date: 2009/2010
```

Answer (score 1):

Linxtelecom is building a brand new datacenter in the center of warsaw, next to the LIM Building (Internet Exchange). I think it will be up and running Q2 of 2011.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that one big company is planning to open new datacenter only for third parties (like colocation or dedicated servers). It will be located in Warsaw, but I don't know the exact location. It should be running in 2011, probably Q1/Q2.

Answer (score 0):

Tried, gave up. I am now hoting with IpExchange in Nürnberg (well, close to - supurb). Perfect service.